# How to create Continuous Rounded Corners in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

In iOS, you can make corners smooth using [continuous rounded corners](https://medium.com/fueled-engineering/continuous-rounded-corners-with-uikit-b575d50ab232). how can I Make the same smooth corners in React Native?

[image]

Red: Normal radius | Orange: Smooth corner

Answer (score 1):

```
<View style={{borderCurve: "continuous" }} />
```

[View style props, React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#bordercurve-ios)